# Why does the normal distribution maximize entropy, given a fixed mu and sigma?

Tags: normal-distribution, entropy

Lets say you want a prior distribution $p$ for a random variable $X \in \mathbb{R}$ which is known to have the mean $\mu$ and the standard deviation $\sigma$. This distribution should maximize the entropy

$$h(X) = - \int p_X(x) \log_2 p_X(x) \mathrm{d}x$$

### My thoughts

The normal distribution has the probability density function

$$f(x \; | \; \mu, \sigma^2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\sigma^2\pi} } \; e^{ -\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} }$$

This means the entropy is

$$
\begin{align}
    c &:= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\sigma^2\pi} }\\
h(X) &= - c \int e^{ -\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} }  \left (c - \log_2(e)  \cdot  \frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} \right ) \mathrm{d} x\\
&= - c \int e^{ -\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} }  c \mathrm{d} x + c  \int e^{ -\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} }\log_2(e)  \cdot  \frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}  \mathrm{d} x\\
&= -c + c  \frac{\log_2(e)}{2 \sigma} \int e^{ -\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} }  \cdot (x-\mu)^2 \mathrm{d} x\\
\end{align}
$$

but I don't think this is helpful to prove that the normal distribution maximizes the entropy, given that we know the distribution has a mean of $\mu$ and a standard deviation of $\sigma$.

Comment: Do you know variation calculus? You can use Lagrangian multipliers method to prove that normal distribution maximize entropy.